# MC4SF.Contact: execution of AfterUpdate

Tags: dlrs

I've created a DLRS on contact object. In the DLRS, I have created a lookup relationship between Contact and a custom object. When I run the calculation using DLRS, some contact records are showing the sum of amount but majority or records fail. I looked at the Lookup  Rollup Summary logs and found below errors:

```
MC4SF.Contact: execution of AfterUpdate

caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 7 with id a0O1200000LFTZmEAP; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

(MC4SF) : CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY ()
```

Below is another error from the logs

```
The formula in the "Set Street Address Type (Home)" rule or process is invalid due to the following:<br/>The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our <A href="javascript:openPopupFocusEscapePounds('https://help.salesforce.com/apex/htdoor?body=%2Ftrain%2FonlineSupport.jsp&loc=support&language=en_US&release=218.9&instance=CS10', 'Help', 1024, 768, 'width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,directories=no,location=yes,dependant=no', false, false);" title="support (New Window)">support</a> page. : CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY ()
The formula in the "Set Other Address Type (Home)" rule or process is invalid due to the following:<br/>The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our <A href="javascript:openPopupFocusEscapePounds('https://help.salesforce.com/apex/htdoor?body=%2Ftrain%2FonlineSupport.jsp&loc=support&language=en_US&release=218.9&instance=CS10', 'Help', 1024, 768, 'width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,directories=no,location=yes,dependant=no', false, false);" title="support (New Window)">support</a> page. : CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY ()
```

I'm new to DLRS. Can someone please provide some guidance how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: There is a [DLRS support group here](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009O5pCAE).  Note that MC4SF is Mailchimp, and "Set Street Address Type" and "Set Other Address Type" seem to be Approval Processes.

Comment: @DavidCheng - Thanks for providing the link to DLRS support group. I've posted this question in that group as well.